# GraphDB Free fails to respond

Tags: graphdb

I'm using GraphDB Free 8.4.1 in research project and sometimes it fails to respond to request. There are no errors, no exceptions in GraphDB logs, GraphDB is running as server+workbench with default configuration.

However, i have exception in component, that is requesting the GraphDB server.

The exception is:

```
org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.RepositoryException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.http.HTTPRepositoryConnection.exportStatements(HTTPRepositoryConnection.java:287)
at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.http.HTTPRepositoryConnection.getStatements(HTTPRepositoryConnection.java:269)
at x.y.semantic.Repository.loadGraph(Repository.java:90)
```

The piece of code, where exception occurs:

```
ValueFactory factory = SimpleValueFactory.getInstance();
RepositoryConnection connection = repository.getConnection();

// exception happens in getStatements here:
RepositoryResult<Statement> result = connection.getStatements(null, null, null, true, factory.createIRI(contextURI));
```

Can you, please, help me to identify, where problem is?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I assume that `resposity.getConnection` is the line 90?

Comment: line 90 is connection.getStatements

Answer (score 0):

GraphDB Free has a limitation of two concurrent connections. I suspect the issues is caused by GDB-1975 "GraphDB Free freezes when multiple concurrent queries are executed". You can easily reproduce the issue with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    RepositoryConnection repCon = repository.getConnection();
    String queryString = "select * where {?s ?p ?o}";

    try {
        TupleQuery tupleQuery = repCon.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, queryString);

        //stops working after the 5th iteration
        TupleQueryResult queryResult = tupleQuery.evaluate();
    } finally {

        //this does not close the connection because the queryResult was not closed
        repCon.close();
    }
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

The code does not close the `queryResult` iterator so the RDF4J leaves the connection open. I recommend you to use the autocloseable Java construct and always close all iterators or to upgrade to 8.6 or later version where the bug was fixed.